# Fluid inflow simulation won't stop overflowing even after using keyframes

Tags: physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation

So I was watching this YouTube tutorial that keeps the fluid animation going while stopping the flow from overflowing at a certain point, using keyframes. Following exactly what they did, as you can see in this mock file, I turned on "Use Flow" with a keyframe inserted at 5, immediately followed by another keyframe inserted at 6 without the Use Flow, but nothing would change.

[image: keyframe 5]
[image: keyframe 6][image: keyframe 7 & onwards]

my file:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing will change"? It seems to work, maybe under Cache click on Free All and Bake again?

Answer (score 1):

as moonboots wrote in the comments, it looks like that you baked your simulation.

By this Blender ignores any change you made until you bake again.

So either you can delete your bake or e.g. use these settings (replay, uncheck is resumable):

[image]

by this Blender does not bake but calculates the sim always. This might be the better settings until you know how it should look like. If you are satisfied with your sim result, then you should bake.

Comment: I re-baked it multiple times but it didn't seem to work for me. Is this an error? Or perhaps I did something incorrectly with my keyframes although I clearly followed the tutorial?

Comment: you did nothing wrong. It worked for me with your file. What Blender version r u using? is your cache path ok?